# Ubuntu 18.04LTS hangs on wake from hibernate. Time seems to jump to extremely high value. Swap seems large enough. Help!

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, suspend, swap, hibernate

I've always had issues with my Precision 5530 (16 GB ram, Quadro P2000, Intel 8850H)when hibernating. It runs Ubuntu 18.04 + NVidia 410 drivers (via apt). Never had issues with the graphics drivers. I just reinstalled the system, so it has minimal modifications, but still nothing has changed.

At first, before I modified the swap configuration, there was a swap file of 2 GB. When waking from hibernate only a black screen with a blinking cursor (underscore) would be shown. No response when trying to open TTY terminals.

I realized that the swap file might be too small to hibernate, and from the previous installation there was still a 34 GB swap partition I hadn't bothered to refuse, so after setting resume= to the UUID in the grub configuration and initramfs-tools, updating grub and ramfs and mounting the partition on startup, I tried again. Now, on wake-up I was displayed by some rather crptic message, and system time seems to jump to extremely high numbers. Still, TTY is unresponsive and I have to force shutdown my system.

I'm a little a wit's end here. I included one syslog, where the hang occurs before the shutdown at Dec 23 23:00:08. If anyone can shed some light on this I would be very grateful.

Small update: running suspend to idle manually

```
echo freeze > /sys/power/state
```

gives me the underscore screen hang. Suspending from the GUI gives me the second type of hang.

[Here's the full log.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lu4gTT6sQ_sFLdUYl9DbkWJ18TmkaAjS)

Minute or so up to freeze:

```
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 wpa_supplicant[942]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-57 noise=9999 txrate=115600
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   57.867529] CPU3: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   57.867530] CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   57.867531] CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   57.867532] CPU11: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   57.867557] CPU9: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   57.867559] CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   57.867561] CPU9: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   57.867563] CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   57.867563] CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   57.867564] CPU8: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   57.867566] CPU10: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   57.867567] CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   57.867568] CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   57.867573] CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   57.868523] CPU3: Core temperature/speed normal
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   57.868524] CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   57.868524] CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   57.868524] CPU9: Core temperature/speed normal
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   57.868525] CPU11: Package temperature/speed normal
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   57.868525] CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   57.868526] CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   57.868526] CPU9: Package temperature/speed normal
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   57.868556] CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   57.868557] CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   57.868558] CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   57.868559] CPU8: Package temperature/speed normal
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   57.868560] CPU10: Package temperature/speed normal
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   57.868560] CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 systemd[1]: Starting Stop ureadahead data collection...
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 systemd[1]: Started Stop ureadahead data collection.
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 dhclient[2401]: DHCPACK of 192.168.178.13 from 192.168.178.1
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1545602370.9756] dhcp4 (wlp59s0):   address 192.168.178.13
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1545602370.9756] dhcp4 (wlp59s0):   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1545602370.9756] dhcp4 (wlp59s0):   gateway 192.168.178.1
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1545602370.9756] dhcp4 (wlp59s0):   lease time 3600
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1545602370.9756] dhcp4 (wlp59s0):   nameserver '84.116.46.23'
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1545602370.9757] dhcp4 (wlp59s0):   nameserver '84.116.46.22'
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1545602370.9757] dhcp4 (wlp59s0):   domain name 'dynamic.ziggo.nl'
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1545602370.9757] dhcp4 (wlp59s0): state changed unknown -> bound
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 avahi-daemon[866]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp59s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.178.13.
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 avahi-daemon[866]: New relevant interface wlp59s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 avahi-daemon[866]: Registering new address record for 192.168.178.13 on wlp59s0.IPv4.
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1545602370.9772] device (wlp59s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 whoopsie[1344]: [22:59:30] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1545602370.9776] device (wlp59s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1545602370.9778] device (wlp59s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1545602370.9779] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 dhclient[2401]: bound to 192.168.178.13 -- renewal in 1585 seconds.
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1545602370.9808] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1545602370.9809] policy: set 'Ziggo25AD4' (wlp59s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1545602370.9811] device (wlp59s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 nm-dispatcher: req:3 'up' [wlp59s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 nm-dispatcher: req:3 'up' [wlp59s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 gsd-sharing[1735]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-user-share-webdav.service not loaded.
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 gsd-sharing[1735]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit rygel.service not loaded.
Dec 23 22:59:30 lars-Precision-5530 gsd-sharing[1735]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-remote-desktop.service not loaded.
Dec 23 22:59:31 lars-Precision-5530 PackageKit: resolve transaction /147_ccbdcaca from uid 1000 finished with success after 242ms
Dec 23 22:59:31 lars-Precision-5530 avahi-daemon[866]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp59s0.IPv6 with address fe80::e15e:1377:7f0c:b0b1.
Dec 23 22:59:31 lars-Precision-5530 avahi-daemon[866]: New relevant interface wlp59s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Dec 23 22:59:31 lars-Precision-5530 avahi-daemon[866]: Registering new address record for fe80::e15e:1377:7f0c:b0b1 on wlp59s0.*.
Dec 23 22:59:33 lars-Precision-5530 NetworkManager[930]: <info>  [1545602373.3018] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Dec 23 22:59:33 lars-Precision-5530 nm-dispatcher: req:4 'connectivity-change': new request (1 scripts)
Dec 23 22:59:33 lars-Precision-5530 nm-dispatcher: req:4 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
Dec 23 22:59:33 lars-Precision-5530 whoopsie[1344]: [22:59:33] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
Dec 23 22:59:33 lars-Precision-5530 whoopsie[1344]: [22:59:33] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
Dec 23 22:59:33 lars-Precision-5530 whoopsie[1344]: [22:59:33] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
Dec 23 22:59:33 lars-Precision-5530 whoopsie[1344]: [22:59:33] online
Dec 23 22:59:34 lars-Precision-5530 PackageKit: resolve transaction /148_badccdcc from uid 1000 finished with success after 259ms
Dec 23 22:59:45 lars-Precision-5530 boltd[1197]: power: got event for guard '2' (10)
Dec 23 22:59:45 lars-Precision-5530 boltd[1197]: power: guard '2' for 'fwupd' deactivated
Dec 23 22:59:45 lars-Precision-5530 boltd[1197]: power: shutdown scheduled (T-20.00s)
Dec 23 22:59:53 lars-Precision-5530 gnome-software-service.desktop[2492]: Unable to acquire bus name 'org.gnome.Software'
Dec 23 22:59:57 lars-Precision-5530 systemd-timesyncd[757]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.91.157:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Dec 23 23:00:05 lars-Precision-5530 boltd[1197]: power: setting force_power to OFF
Dec 23 23:00:07 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   95.748031] xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: remove, state 4
Dec 23 23:00:07 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   95.748036] usb usb4: USB disconnect, device number 1
Dec 23 23:00:07 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   95.748253] xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: USB bus 4 deregistered
Dec 23 23:00:07 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   95.748294] xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
Dec 23 23:00:07 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   95.748298] xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: remove, state 4
Dec 23 23:00:07 lars-Precision-5530 upowerd[1112]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:3a:00.0/usb4/4-0:1.0
Dec 23 23:00:07 lars-Precision-5530 upowerd[1112]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:3a:00.0/usb3/3-0:1.0
Dec 23 23:00:07 lars-Precision-5530 upowerd[1112]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:3a:00.0/usb4
Dec 23 23:00:07 lars-Precision-5530 upowerd[1112]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:3a:00.0/usb3
Dec 23 23:00:07 lars-Precision-5530 boltd[1197]: [c9030000-0070-Precision 15 M5530         ] removed (/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.0/0000:04:00.0/domain0/0-0)
Dec 23 23:00:07 lars-Precision-5530 boltd[1197]: [c9030000-0070-Precision 15 M5530         ] dbus: unexported
Dec 23 23:00:07 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   95.748303] usb usb3: USB disconnect, device number 1
Dec 23 23:00:07 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   95.748489] xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: Host halt failed, -19
Dec 23 23:00:07 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   95.748496] xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: Host not accessible, reset failed.
Dec 23 23:00:07 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   95.748617] xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: USB bus 3 deregistered
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 boltd[1197]: domain: 'domain0' removed
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 boltd[1197]: dbus: domain0 unexported: ok
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 boltd[1197]: domain: 'domain0' removed
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   96.251302] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: stopping RX ring 0
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   96.251314] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: disabling interrupt at register 0x38200 bit 12 (0xffffffff -> 0xffffefff)
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   96.251317] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: stopping TX ring 0
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   96.251324] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: disabling interrupt at register 0x38200 bit 0 (0xffffffff -> 0xfffffffe)
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   96.251326] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: control channel stopped
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   96.251358] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: freeing RX ring 0
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   96.251363] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: freeing TX ring 0
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   96.251367] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: shutdown
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   96.291016] pci_bus 0000:03: Allocating resources
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   96.291061] pcieport 0000:03:01.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 05-39] add_size 1000
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   96.291075] pcieport 0000:03:02.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 3a] add_size 1000
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   96.291077] pcieport 0000:03:02.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 3a] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   96.291091] pcieport 0000:02:00.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 03-3a] add_size 2000
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   96.291094] pcieport 0000:02:00.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x2000]
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   96.291094] pcieport 0000:02:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x2000]
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   96.291095] pcieport 0000:02:00.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x2000]
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   96.291096] pcieport 0000:02:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x2000]
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   96.291099] pcieport 0000:03:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   96.291100] pcieport 0000:03:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   96.291100] pcieport 0000:03:01.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   96.291101] pcieport 0000:03:01.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   96.291102] pcieport 0000:03:02.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   96.291102] pcieport 0000:03:02.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   96.291104] pcieport 0000:03:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   96.291105] pcieport 0000:03:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   96.291105] pcieport 0000:03:02.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   96.291106] pcieport 0000:03:02.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   96.291107] pcieport 0000:03:01.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
Dec 23 23:00:08 lars-Precision-5530 kernel: [   96.291108] pcieport 0000:03:01.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the exact same specs as your model. However I've got mine finally working with the following setup.

- Ubuntu 18.04
- No changes to grub
- Installed all the `linux-generic-hwe` packages
- installed the nvidia-390 driver

After this everything (suspend ect.) seems to be working in Gnome Wayland and ARMA 3 gives me decent frame rates. I've only tried it today and therefore haven't really invested much time into Gnome Xorg or i3wm. However it seems to crash everytime I select one of those environments.

Comment: After a few iterations I ended up at exactly the same configuration as you described. Civ 6 runs smooth, as well as rather good performance of some CUDA code. Driver 410 just seems to buggy at the moment, and for even more stability I usually select the Intel graphics when not using the GPU. Xorg  makes the GPU crash a lot. On Wayland suspend works for me too.

Comment: Do you change the graphics card with Bumblebee?

Comment: Intel prime select, installed with Nvidia drivers. Do you know how it works?

Comment: Not yet, can you explain it to me?

Comment: Check if it is installed (e.g. by running "which prime-select"). If it is, you can query the current selection by executing "prime-select query" which gives you either intel or nvidia. To change mode, run "prime-select intel" or "prime-select nvidia", and reboot. If you boot with prime-select intel, your graphics card will not be turned on, and drivers will not be loaded. I don't think there is a nice way to turn on your graphics card without a reboot, so keep in mind that you need to reboot! Reduced power consumption is a benefit from using the intel graphics, but it is much less powerful.